# Prompt user for entry, thank them for entry Javascript

Tags: javascript, prompt

The first prompt shows up, and nothing else happens, even if I enter a number or try to push through the prompt without entering anything.

So far I've written this code:

```
var ratingEntry = prompt("We would like for you to review . Please enter a 
rating between 0.0 - 5.0?");

if (ratingEntry === undefined) {
    prompt('Please enter a rating from 0-5!');
} else if (ratingEntry === 0) {
teacherRatings.push('ratingEntry');
    prompt('Thank you!');
} else if (ratingEntry === 1) {
    teacherRatings.push('ratingEntry');
    prompt('Thank you!');
}
```

I've tweaked it several times to no avail.

Comment: what libraries are you using?  Browser or NOde Js?

Comment: This code only runs once, it does not run again once you change the value of `ratingEntry`

Comment: You are using strict comparison (`===`). `prompt` returns a string, so `'1'===1` will never be true. Use `var ratingEntry = parseInt(prompt(...), 10)` and change the first if to `if(ratingEntry)`.

Answer (score 0):

A `prompt` will return a `string`.  And you need to always capture it to compare, so I would do:

```
var message = "We would like for you to review . Please enter a rating between 0.0 - 5.0?";

while(ratingEntry = prompt(message)) {
    if (ratingEntry === '' || ratingEntry < 0 || ratingEntry > 5) {
        message = 'Please enter a rating from 0-5!');
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

etc.  because you are using `===` which compares value as well as type (e.g. `1 === 1` and `1 !== '1'`, but `1 == '1'`)

Comment: Do you mean `ratingEntry = prompt(`?

Comment: I mean `prompt` will return a string, so when you do `===` you have to check against a string.  Or cast `ratingEntry` to a number.

Comment: `prompt()` will return a string but you aren't getting capturing it at all. Should it be an `alert()` or should that `prompt()` put the value into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

To compare Integer you need to first parse `ratingEntry` into `Integer` then compare and for first condition It is coming blank not undefined so put both check with `OR` in first condition.

```
var ratingEntry = prompt("We would like for you to review . Please enter a rating between 0.0 - 5.0?");
if (typeof ratingEntry === undefined || ratingEntry.trim() == '') {
    prompt('Please enter a rating from 0-5!');
} else if (parseInt(ratingEntry) === 0) {
    teacherRatings.push('ratingEntry');
    prompt('Thank you!');
} else if (parseInt(ratingEntry) === 1) {
    teacherRatings.push('ratingEntry');
    prompt('Thank you!');
}
```

and last thing I am not sure what you are doing with this code but It should be like this
Use
`teacherRatings.push(ratingEntry)`;

Instead of

```
teacherRatings.push('ratingEntry');  //this push ratingEntry as string in teacherRatings not as a value of variable
```

Comment: it's part of a project in which i'm trying to push the numerical input into a function to return an average of multiple entries. but....one horrible problem at a time...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that prompt return a string and you do check for equality without type coersion.

`1 === 1 is true
"1" === 1 is false`

Basically `"1"` is a string, and `1`is a integer.

Change `===`to `==` and you would ignore "type" check. Or just check for `"1"` instead of `1`

Comment: right... i have:
```var ratingEntry = prompt("We would like for you to review . Please enter a rating between 0.0 - 5.0?");
console.log(ratingEntry);

while (ratingEntry < 0 || ratingEntry > 5 || ratingEntry === "" || ratingEntry == null) {
  ratingEntry = prompt('Please enter a rating from 0-5!');
  //ratingEntry = parseInt(ratingEntry);
  //parseInt('ratingEntry');
}
alert('Thank you!');

ratingsArray = [3, 2, 4]
ratingsArray.push(ratingEntry);
//parseInt(ratingEntry);
console.log(ratingsArray);```

and i can't figure out how to get parseInt to work (thus the commented)

Comment: Remove the quotes from ratinEntry. Also parseInt returns the value, so ratingEntry=parseInt(ratingEntry);

Answer (score 0):

You may want to parse the input to Float and then use a while loop until the input is valid:

```
var ratingEntry = prompt("We would like for you to review . Please enter a rating between 0.0 - 5.0?");
var ratingNum = parseFloat(ratingEntry)

while (isNaN(ratingNum) || ratingNum < 0 || ratingNum > 5) {
  ratingNum = parseFloat(prompt('Please enter a rating from 0-5!'));
}
teacherRatings.push(ratingNum);
prompt('Thank you!');
```